# How to get the multiple data from database of same Id or same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application I want to display the multiple record  of same  id or same name which is stored previously in view, but in my application only current data is displayed of same id, multiple data is displayed but not for same id, its for different  id.
My application is Attendance management system , in which the employee who is login and logout ,I store the time in attendance table and when i display the attendence it only display the today login ,logout time bt i want to display the previous data of same emp id,for example- EmpId =5 suppose he login monday so his login and logout time is display in view and also stored in database and same process for same is for tuesday but when I display the tuesday data Monday data is not display I want to display monday data also which is stored in database.

Comment: Id's of records should be uniqe. You shoul not have multiple records with same id in best practice. Now, can you show a little example of your data?

Comment: Maybe the "multiple records" are actually referring another record with unique ID. Foreign key?

Comment: Too little to guess your problem. Provide more information i.e. describe your data model briefly, the code you are using to fetch, etc to get help faster.

Comment: Please, post sample code